# React Native app cache images even the response headers say "no-cache"?

Tags: react-native, cache-control

my app fetch a lot of images from S3 bucket using cloudfront. All of the images have "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" in cache control headers. The weird thing here is react native keeps the cached images in data > data > com.myapp > cache. Is this a normal thing or a bug in RN? I'm using RN 0.33.0